# Using a pointer to traverse a dynamic allocation of classes

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

In the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class A
{
public:
    int a, b, c;
    A()
    {
        a=b=c=0;
    }
};
int main()
{
    A* a=new A();
    A* b=a;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        a = new A();
        cout<<a->a<<endl;
        cout<<a->b<<endl;
        cout<<a->c<<endl;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout<< b->a <<endl;
        cout<< b->b <<endl;
        cout<< b->c <<endl;
        b++;
    }

}
```

I am making a quasi array using pointer a. However, when I try to read this array using b, I get garbage values. The problem is that b++ isn't incrementing b by a value equal to the size of an object of class A. How can I read my "array" of classes using b?

Answer (score 2):

Per your implementation, `a` points to a single instance of `A`, not an array.

To create an array,

```
A* a = new A[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    A* b = a+i;
    cout << b->a << endl;
    cout << b->b << endl;
    cout << b->c << endl;
}
```